# Dependencies error at the time of installing nodejs.rpm using rpm in Centos 7?

Tags: node.js, centos7, rpm

I am trying to install nodejs.rpm in Centos 7 using rpm installer. Referred this [link](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/okey-x86_64/nodejs-10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html). Downloaded rpm binary package from referred link [here](http://repo.okay.com.mx/centos/7/x86_64/release//nodejs-10.13.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm).

The files downloaded and available in my local directory. Then execute the following command

```
rpm -ivh nodejs-10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

End up in the following error

```
warning: nodejs-10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID ac25decd: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    http-parser >= 2.7.0 is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    libhttp_parser.so.2()(64bit) is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    libnghttp2.so.14()(64bit) is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    libnghttp2_14_17_1 >= 1.34.0 is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    libuv >= 1:1.23.2 is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    libuv.so.1()(64bit) is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
    npm = 1:6.4.1-1.10.13.0.2.el7 is needed by nodejs-1:10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64
```

I appreciate any help to resolve this warning and error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- downloading yourself all dependencies (painful!) and then installing all of them with `rpm -ivh *.rpm`
- using a decent package manager like `yum` or `dnf` that manages all dependencies for you. I would suggest you to try running simply `yum install nodejs8` or even `yum install ./nodejs-10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm` if you really want to install the exact version that you downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I started using yum repository to install nodejs specific version and it's dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I used YUM repository to satisfied dependency chain of installing nodejs in centos 7.

When I tried to install using yum command doesn't download all dependencies automatically still few dependency error occurred.

```
yum install nodejs-10.13.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

To resolve this:

- Created a directory in a root directory named(A).
- Download those few dependencies individually(you can get each rpm file
  in google search).
- Place all dependencies rpm files along with nodejs rpm in
  directory A.

Then run this command to create repodata directory automatically inside A.

```
createrepo A
```

Create a repository file named(local.repo) in path /etc/yum.repos.d

```
[NodeUpgrade]
name=Node Version Upgrade - NodeUpgrade
baseurl=file:///A
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

NodeUpgrade is repository name. This can be listed when execute command

```
yum repolist

repo id           repo name                                   status
NodeUpgrade       Node Version Upgrade - NodeUpgrade            7
debuginfo         debuginfo                                    3160
```

Install using  yum:

```
sudo yum install nodejs
```

List available nodejs to find nodejs installed and make sure the repo name matches with the one specified in local.repo

```
yum info nodejs

Installed Packages
Name        : nodejs
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 10.13.0
Release     : 2.el7
Size        : 27 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : NodeUpgrade
Summary     : JavaScript runtime
URL         : http://nodejs.org/
License     : MIT and ASL 2.0 and ISC and BSD
Description : Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript
            : runtime for easily building fast, scalable network
            : applications. Node.js uses an event-driven,
            : non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and
            : efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time
            : applications that run across distributed devices.
```

Thanks for your suggestion @Chris Maes. I hope this explanation will bring a clear picture.